# Laravel errors after backing up an old version

Tags: laravel

This is what I get after copying all my laravel backup files from an older version:
[image]

Someone has any idea why it happens and how to make it work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to specify API_PREFIX and API_DOMAIN in the Laravel .env File and for the second screen you need to enter the project and generate a key with artisan : php artisan key:generate